# Hover Translation Tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, translate

I apologize in advance if this question violates any forum rules.
I have tried many google searches but have been unable to come up with the results I am looking for.

Basically, I would like a hover translation tool to be developed for Burmese -> English.  I know there are many tools available, but I have not encountered one specifically for this pair.  I have found a tool which I like, and after which I would like to model this one.  It is called Rikaichan, and is available at http://www.polarcloud.com/rikaichan as an add-on for Firefox and Chrome.

I have a beginner/intermediate knowledge of html, css, javascript, jQuery, and PHP.  I have a dictionary on my computer that can be searched in either language.

My question is this:  How does one develop a hover translation tool?

I am not looking for all the code, but just for some help getting started.  Based on my limited knowledge, I would guess something like this.  The tool has to only attempt to translate if it is Burmese.  There are a variety of Burmese fonts, and not all of them are Unicode.  So, I don't know if it would have to be developed separately for the different fonts or not.  So, let's pretend they are all Unicode.  So, when a user hovers over some text, using a javascript/jquery mouseover event, a search is triggered.  The search term is the word hovered and it searches in the dictionary file.  When encountered, the text pops up and shows the user the possible words.

But, I'm just kind of stuck.  Any help?